# Refactor Rename History in CDT

Tags: refactoring, rename, eclipse-cdt

Why CDT does not save the refactor history for rename of functions and variables ?
(However JDT will save all the rename refactoring done in the source code)

Is it a limitation for CDT Refactoring plugin ? How to save rename of functions and variables to Refactoring History ?

If it is not inbuilt in CDT refactoring plugin , is it possible to develop a custom plugin for saving the Refactor->Rename of variables/functions ?

Comment: It should be possible to write your own plugin to keep track of every place in the CDT tree that is modified. You can then use a custom UNDO step to undo those places.  Expect it to be a lot of work.

Comment: CDT does add refactoring to the UNDO stack. Can you please provide details as to how it doesn't, i.e. have you found a bug where a specific case is not being added. (I tried Rename a method and it undid the change.)